# How to use the "defines" parameter of Microsoft.Hadoop.WebHCat.Protocol.WebHCatHttpClient.CreateHiveJob?

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight, hcatalog

I guess `defines` allows passing parameters to the Hive query, but I haven't found any documentation or usage examples. How do I use these parameters in the query?

Answer (score 1):

I am using defines parameter from powershell, but hopefully it will help you.

So first in PowerShell script I am writing something like following:

```
[HashTable] $defines
$defines = @{}
$defines.Add("someContainerUrl",${someContainerUrl})
```

Then I am using this new defines variable when I am calling the HDInsight:

```
$jobDef = New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -Query $hiveQuery -JobName $jobName -Defines $defines -StatusFolder "/JobStatus/Hive"
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob –Cluster $clusterName –JobDefinition $jobDef
```

Then in my hive code, I can use this defines variable for example as following:

```
ADD FILES
    ${hiveconf:someContainerUrl}/SomeFile.exe;
```

I think this article might be of help to you as well:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/02/13/how-to-pass-hadoop-configuration-values-for-a-job-via-hdinsight-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx